# How do I share a Selenium WebDriver element using Python multiprocessing and shared memory?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, python-multiprocessing

I'm trying to do an webscraping project. While doing the project I thought whether multiprocessing can be introduced into this. For sharing data between processes, I've used the shared memory of multiprocessing. Although it works fine for basic python types, my problem occurs when I try to share an webdriver element.

I've tried in the following way:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options 
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
import multiprocessing as mp
import ctypes

path = "C:\\Program Files\\chromedriver.exe"
def extract(i, x, name, l):
    # trying to extract data from web page
    # here the 'name' parameter is a list of web elements which is defined below inside if __name__ == '__main__'
    # 'i' is the index of the list element to be extracted
    # x is a constant
    # l is the multiprocessing Lock() for file writing
if __name__ == '__main__':

    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = path, options=options)

    driver.get("Some URL")
    tbody = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '---') # this is a table in the html page containing list of data
    name = tbody.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME,'titleColumn') # this is a list of web elements, each element is a row in the table
    file=open('myFile.txt','w+')
    x = len(name)
    procs=[]
    l = mp.Lock()
    print(type(name[0]))
    nameLi = mp.Manager().list()
    nameLi.append(name) # the problem is here, the list is not being saved, says "Can't Pickle Local Object"
    did = mp.Value(ctypes.c_int, x)
    for i in range(6,10):
        p = mp.Process(target=extract, args=(i, did , nameLi, l))
        p.start()
        procs.append(p)
    for p in procs:
        p.join()
    driver.quit()
```

When I try to run this file, the first page gets loaded and all the variables *name, tbody* works fine. However, after loading the first web page the program stops and shows `AttributeError: Can't pickle local object '\_createenviron.\<locals\>.encodekey'`. I need to have access to this *name* variable in the *extract* function. What is the right way to do this. And also please correct me if I'm doing it in the wrong way. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you need to share webdriver? A single webdriver instance is equivalent of a single session. It does not make sense to share it.

Comment: But each process created by multiprocess API instantiates new interpreter according to doc. However, I might be wrong about this (interpreted in the wrong way); but one thing I noticed that my webdriver doesn't work when I try to access in the "extract" function.